# Why does the camera not start everytime?

Tags: android

I want to blink flashlight on incoming call. Everytime this code is going in service method i.e its running fine, its starting the service fine but the problem is its unable to start camera service everytime. If camera is running the blinking is not stopping if the call state changes. How could i start camera everytime and stop the blinking if the call state changes??
The code i used...

in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
```

in service

```
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
        try {
            cam = Camera.open();
            p = cam.getParameters();

            String myString = "0101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101011";
            long blinkDelay = 150;
            cam.setParameters(p);

            for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {

                     if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){

                break;                  

                }else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                break;  
                }               

                if (myString.charAt(i) == '0') {
                    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                    cam.setParameters(p);
                } else {
                    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    cam.setParameters(p);
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(blinkDelay);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(tag, e.toString());
                    p.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                    cam.setParameters(p);
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.d(tag, "in catch1");
            Log.d(tag, e.toString());

    }
}else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
    cam.release();
    stopSelf();
    }else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
        cam.release();
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

The logcat is not stopping and it is still running , crazy is the tag that i declared i got this

```
    03-11 23:11:08.129: W/CameraService(133): CameraService::connect X (pid 942) rejected (existing client).
03-11 23:11:08.139: D/crazy(942): in catch1
03-11 23:11:08.139: D/crazy(942): java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
```

Comment: yes its working fine sometimes but sometimes it doesnot... i declared the permissions above that i have used...

Comment: i have catched exception for camera.open()....it shows the runtime exception i.e unable to start camera service....bt i have catched that exception thats why its not stopping the app

Comment: Can you add the error message and the stack trace to your post, please?

Comment: @Michelle sure give a minute...

Comment: this  time it using this camera in intent service so it giving huge text earlier i was using this in broadcastreceiver than i got stacktrace from e is unable to start camera service

Comment: sir i ran it again and i got this stacktrace, crazy was the tag i declared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check out the [Camera documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28int%29), one reason that opening the camera could throw a `RuntimeException` is that another process is using the camera, which is what the error log seems to indicate. Check what other processes are running and make sure nothing else is using the camera (you should also be properly handling this error).

You should also make sure *your* application is calling `release()` on the camera, so that you aren't blocking other applications from using it.

Comment: It may be the reason that other processes are using camera service but  i also want to use this so how could i make camera free from those processes

Comment: It might be your application that's blocking you, if you aren't already releasing the camera when you're done with it. Otherwise, there's no way to boot another process out of the camera, no.

Comment: I released camera still stack trace is sending same exception